# Не отображается background

Tags: css, вёрстка, explorer, internet-explorer

Не отображается `background: rgba(236,239,219,0.9);` в internet explorer 8

Comment: [угадайте почему][1]

[1]:http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

Comment: я знаю что ie8 не поддерживает css3.я хочу узнать решение этой проблемы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#30000000,endColorstr=#30000000);
```

где 30 прозрачность, остальное цвет, в данном случае 000000.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в стилях записать два бэкграунда, первый - png-картинкой с заданным цветом и прозрачностью, второй через rgba

```
background: url('path_to_bg_img/bg_img.png') 0% 0% repeat;
background: rgba(236,239,219,0.9);
```

второе свойство перекроет первое и все современные браузеры отобразят второй бэкграунд, 
ie8, ie7 и т.д. второе свойство не распознают и возьмут бэкграунд из первого свойства.

Comment: не то,прозрачную картинку никак не вставишь

Comment: Сделайте для ie бэкграунд без прозрачности    

`background: rgb(236,239,219);
background: rgba(236,239,219,0.9);`

Comment: не помогает